# understanding property binding in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a naive question. Say I have a input element defined like the below:

```
<input [(ngModel)]=model.username name="username" id="username">
```

The above essentially means that there is now a **PROPERTY** called ngModel defined on the input element which in turn is binded to model.username. All good so far.

Now just for the learning purpose, I access the input element like so:

```
let input = document.getElementbyId('username');
```

And then try to inspect something like `input.ngModel`...boom...there is no such property!

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-target

> Element properties may be the more common targets, but Angular looks
>   first to see if the name is a property of a known directive, as it is
>   in the following example:

```
<div [ngClass]="classes">[ngClass] binding to the classes property</div>
```

> Technically, Angular is matching the name to a directive input, one of
>   the property names listed in the directive's inputs array or a
>   property decorated with @Input(). Such inputs map to the directive's
>   own properties.
>
> If the name fails to match a property of a known directive or element,
>   Angular reports an “unknown directive” error.

So in your case angular found `NgModel` directive with `@Input('ngModel') model: any;`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L112

Comment: makes sense...does the same concept goes with event bindings?

Comment: `Element events may be the more common targets, but Angular looks first to see if the name matches an event property of a known directive, as it does in the following example:` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#target-event

Comment: But as i know unknown event binding doesn't fire error. `<input (unknownEvent)="test()
">` will work without error while `<input [unknownProperty]="test">` will cause error `Can't bind to 'unknownEvent' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

Comment: hmm...help me understand the ngModel part a bit. So this is how it works: ngModelChange event is defined as the @Output property of some directive. So as soon as I change something, the expression gets executed.  Now the expression changes some component property which is then binded a [ngModel]. so ngModel is defined as a '@Input' property of some directive. This ngModel's directive updates the input element internal DOM value property.....

Comment: The expression `[(ngModel)]=model.username` might be rewritten like `[ngModel]="model.username" (ngModelChange)="model.username = $event"`. So when `ngModelChange` is emitted propery gets update and `ngOnChanges` within `ngModel` directive is firing https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L139-L150

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You need also to know that there is `DefaultValueAccessor` which does all work for writing value and listening events https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136066/discussion-between-benerd-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 0):

`[(ngModel)]` provides `two-way data-binding` by binding to the value.

Property binding provides `one-way data binding` from data source to view target. Some examples of property binding are:

```
<input [disabled]="true">
<input [value]="{5 : 'ifSomeCondition()'}"
<input [attr.type]="{'text' : typeIsText()}"
```